# React class styling from css stylesheet not working

Tags: css, reactjs

In my React App, I am trying to load styles for html elements from a CSS stylesheet by assigning styles to classes.

I can get styling for elements, such as h2, p, td, working

**Problem:**

I cannot get styling for classes to work.

**--- UPDATE: The below code appears to be working, and I am not sure what caused it to fail before. I'd delete this question if I could. Thank you for those that helped ---**

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="hide_me">
          <h2>This text should not be visible because it has className "hide_me"</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
h2 {
  color: red;
}

.hide_me {
  display: none;
}
```

**Current Behavior**

I see text in red that should be hidden i.e.
[image]

**Expected behaviour**

No text!

---

Is there a solution that allows me to use CSS stylesheets without installing a new module?

Comment: Hmm there is no reason for this not to work.

Comment: This appears to be working now, and I have no idea why :( Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Mark it as answered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a working example, it's hard to say, but here's a hide/show toggle example (click `Run code snippet`). Try copying/pasting this example into your project and seeing if it works. If it doesn't, then there's something not set up properly with your project, where stylesheets aren't being properly imported.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    
    this.state = { clicks: 0, hidden: false };
    
    this.handleIncreaseClicks = this.handleIncreaseClicks.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonDisplay = this.handleButtonDisplay.bind(this);
  } 
   
  handleIncreaseClicks() {
    this.setState(state => ({ clicks: state.clicks + 1 }));
  }  
   
  handleButtonDisplay() {
    this.setState(state => ({ hidden: !state.hidden }));
  }

  render() {   
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className={`container ${this.state.hidden ? "hide-me" : ""}`}>
          <p className="label">Clicks:</p>
          <button 
            className="clicks" 
            onClick={this.handleIncreaseClicks}
          >
            {this.state.clicks}
          </button>
          <br />
        </div>
        <button 
          className="hide-show-button" 
          onClick={this.handleButtonDisplay}
        >
          {this.state.hidden ? "Show" : "Hide"} Clicks
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.label {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.hide-show-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.hide-show-button {
  background-color: #f56342;
  color: white;
}

.hide-show-button:hover {
  background-color: #be391c;
}

.clicks {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.clicks:hover {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.clicks:focus, .hide-show-button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue as you and fixed by doing a forced refresh. New styles aren't applied on a regular refresh since the browser is using the cached version of that page. A cache issue might explain how this magically went away for you.

You can do a force refresh and clear the page click by shift-clicking the refresh button in Chrome or Firefox.

Refer to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) for more

Answer (score 0):

Check the h2 in dev tools to see if it really has the hide_me class.

Comment: I can put the 'hide_me' class on the parent div, and the issue still remains, and yes, the class is visible in dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a same problem. My project had ASP.NET as a backend. When I changed modules to false in my **webpack.config.js** file, all styles of classes showed up. It should be

```
options: {
    modules: false
}
```

Answer (score -15):

Try reading this official documentation. This will give you a solid understanding of react -> https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html.

Comment: I have read through this documentation, and could only find https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#how-do-i-add-css-classes-to-components about CSS styling which didn't seem to cover css style sheets.

Comment: You could use this one. This will help you style components. https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't require installing a new module?